# DataflowTemplate makes HTTP Call at constructor call

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

The `DataFlowTemplate` that I am using in order to start tasks deployed to Spring Cloud Dataflow executes an HTTP Call to the SCDF server when I am calling the constructor, e.g.
`new DataFlowTemplate(...)`

The problem is that I am deploying SCDF as a docker container next to several other containers. When the constructor is called, the SCDF server is not up yet and it says `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: scdf` (scdf is the network alias of my SCDF container)

I don't understand why its necessary for the client to execute a call at constructor time. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The DataFlowTemplate uses the list of endpoints provided by the service for subsequent calls. I suggest you delay the construction of DataFlowTemplate until you need to interact with SCDF.